# SQL inner join on Microsoft SQL server

Tags: sql-server, select, join

I have two select statements that I want to  join on MS SQL and it fails with syntax error before JOIN and  ON. Where did I go wrong  ?

```
SELECT Id, COUNT(Item) AS Count   FROM DB_1.dbo.table w 
GROUP BY Id, Item
JOIN 
(

SELECT Id, Path, Name FROM DB2.dbo.partition p 
GROUP BY Id, Path, Name
)  
ON w.Id = p.Id
```

Comment: You have your group by in the wrong place. Move it to the end.

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to accomplish... are you wanting to select path/name from the partition table also?  Or are you trying to use it as an exists filter?  What does your source data look like?  What do you want the output to look like?

Comment: @JiggsJedi - I have an Id, common to both tables, first query gets Id of partition, second provides path to that partition. The answer from DenimChicken provides me with the wanted result. Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to join the results of the first and second queries. You also need to have the aliases (`w` and `p`) outside of sub query. Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT Id, COUNT(Item) AS Count FROM DB_1.dbo.table 
  GROUP BY Id, Item) w
JOIN (
  SELECT Id, Path, Name FROM DB2.dbo.partition  
  GROUP BY Id, Path, Name
) p
ON w.Id = p.Id
```

Comment: Wow DenimChicken, you are the best !!! Spent lots of time trying to figure it by myself, but my SQL skills weren't good enough. Thanks A Great lot !